# Is entropy of planets and others bodies proportional to the area?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, holographic-principle

Is entropy of planets and others bodies proportional to the area? If yes, how do I prove that? I know it works for a black hole but, and for others? If no, then the entropy is really proportional to the volume in some cases?  I have seen this proportionality in some cases in thermodynamics.

Answer (score -1):

The total entropy is an integral of the entropy density over the body volume. I do not know if it even makes any sense for planets, though.

Black holes are exotic (thoeretical) objects with non verifiable properties.

Comment: In some places it was said that the entropy of a volume was related to its area and not volume, so the question

Comment: If a body only consists of some **surface**, then maybe, but in general case the science says clearly how to calculate entropy of a 3D body.